# MVC 4: CRUD operation on complex object of Collections

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using for MVC 4. I am putting a simple Model as an example below, but the use case is really complex.

lets assume I am modifying a Team Data.

```
public class Team
{
    string TeamName;
    List<Project> projects;
    List<Employee> employee;
}
```

I should be able to perform CRUD operations on the model above. The requirement is to add Projects and Team members. And clicking Save once should save the team data and collection is holds.

In the UI while editing Team I should be able to add Projects when I click "Add more Projects" as well as Edit Project already added to Team. The same applies for Employee. There is no limit to the number of Projects and Employee I can Add, I mean I should be able to add details dynamically and save it once.

Is there any control or combination of controls/HTML Helpers I can use for this in MVC?

Comment: Sorry not really understanding the question here. You have a List of Projects and employees. You want to add projets and employees to the already existing lists and save it?

Comment: Yes.This example is just to describe the requirement, not a real life example. I have a complex object with 2 or more collection in it and I want to dynamically Add and Update and Save the complex Object at once.